# Integral of the determinant of the Jacobian in complex variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, determinant, complex-integration

Let $f$ be a function that maps a disc $D$ onto a unit square $A$ such that $f(D) = A$. $f$ is holomorphic and one-to-one. Why does $\int_D|f'(x+iy)|^2 \, dx \, dy = 1$?

Comment: What is the radius of the disk?

Comment: The radius is not given.